# What's the difference between "it excites me" and "that excites me"?

Tags: meaning, difference, pronouns

I know the difference between *it* and *that*, but what does *that* mean in the sentence below? Does it mean the same as *it*?

> I reach for the phone,
>   I don't know who to call.
>   **That** excites me.
>   Starving for days,
>   I've been told it's a phase,
>   But they don't see.
>   That I'm holding on to something that I don't seem to catch
>   Now I've been following the streams along,
>   But nothing never last.

Source: [Wake Up Alone Lyrics](https://www.lyricsbox.com/martin-tungevaag-and-raaban-wake-up-alone-lyrics-2zkkhdt.html)

Answer (score 1):

The link within your link for playing the song is not a free-play, so it is difficult to tell what *that* refers to.

It may mean that

> I reach for the phone I dont know who to call

not knowing whom to call excites you, or it may mean

> I reach for the phone I dont know who to call that excites me

you don't know which *person that excites you* to call

Comment: Okay Peter here's an another link but give me an appropriate answer please. Any help will be appreciated        https://youtu.be/BGXqZmDKxM8

Comment: Sorry that link is blocked in the US.

Comment: I've modified the link in the question, but in case this other one is also blocked in the US I've completed the lyrics. There was a typo in OP's link (What I think is a typo, I'd never seen "phase" spelt "fase".

Comment: @Laure Thanks for doing that, its still blocked on Youtube due to copyright. The question is if there is a pause between "call" and "that", only reading lyrics may not bring out the intent since singers don't always follow punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I can see is that "it" may imply something that is more immediate to you in time or space, where "that" implies something not as close. In actuality, I think it's a matter of preference of how the sentence sounds to the author.