# What is the meaning of "that" in "that excites me"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns

> I reach for my phone I don't know who to call. That excites me.
>
> There ain't enough time or days in a week. That excites me.

Source: [Wake Up Alone lyrics](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Tungevaag-Raaban-feat-Clara-Mae/Wake-Up-Alone)

Does it mean that not knowing who to call and not having enough time excites her?

Or does it mean that she doesnt know the person that excites her and there isn't enough time which excites her?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question more than once: [What's the difference between “it excites me” and “that excites me”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129897/whats-the-difference-between-it-excites-me-and-that-excites-me), [What is meaning of *bold* in the sentence below](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129967/what-is-meaning-of-bold-in-the-sentence-below). This is highly discouraged. You are expected to request clarification or wait for more answers.

Comment: **That** is a demonstrative pronoun referring back to the circumstances described in the first clause.  *My brother is coming for a visit. That is exciting news.*

Comment: But that can also refer to which as well euh?